# Go time.Now().UnixNano() convert to milliseconds?

Tags: time, go, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

How can I get Unix time in Go in milliseconds?

I have the following function:

```
func makeTimestamp() int64 {
    return time.Now().UnixNano() % 1e6 / 1e3
}
```

I need less precision and only want milliseconds.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

#### The 2021 answer:

As of go v1.17, the [`time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time) package added `UnixMicro()` and `UnixMilli()`, so the correct answer would be: `time.Now().UnixMilli()`

#### For go v.1.16 and earlier:

Just divide it:

```
func makeTimestamp() int64 {
    return time.Now().UnixNano() / 1e6
}
```

`1e6`, i.e. 1 000 000, is the number of nanoseconds in a millisecond.

Here is an example that you can compile and run to see the output

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := makeTimestamp()

    fmt.Printf("%d \n", a)
}

func makeTimestamp() int64 {
    return time.Now().UnixNano() / 1e6
}
```

Comment: The above calculation doesn't really make sense. You don't divide nanoseconds by miliseconds.
It happens to be the case that golang choses to represent times down to nanosecond and the constant 'Millisecond' is 1,000,000.

Mathematically speaking, calculation should be: `time.Now().UnixNano() * (time.Nanosecond / time.Millisecond)`. However it's best to change the order because of integer division: `time.Nanosecond * time.Now().UnixNano() / time.Millisecond`

Comment: Probably need some casts.. o/w should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that. Note I didn't say you get the wrong result. It's that the calculation doesn't make sense and you're using information about go's constants.
If tomorrow go has a new version that chooses higher precision for time units, for example, `time.Nanosecond == 10 `and `time.Millisecond == 10,000,000`, your code breaks

Comment: @Jonno all built-in constants (and library methods) are guaranteed for the 1.x release cycle. https://golang.org/doc/go1compat

Comment: thanks for that. You're welcome to rely on that guarantee, but this is in effect a Y2K bug. It may break at some point in the future. Why choose the wrong mathematical representation?

Comment: @Jonno I'm not sure what you're talking about, Nanoseconds / Milliseconds are mathematical constants. http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/time.go#L450

Comment: they are arbitrary constants. They may change in the future. The time package currently "works" in nanosecond precision, but that's an arbitrary choice leading to setting time.Millisecond = 1,000,000. Note that even in the same file you referenced, time.Milisecond is set to 1000 * Microsecond, because mathematically speaking that's what it should represent.
I'm going offline - Hope my explanation helps

Comment: -1 This is just wrong. Your units don't add up. Look up dimensional analysis from physics. Your result does not represent time.

Comment: @OneOfOne You got the right answer and you proved it in your code.

Comment: Quick answer for busy peoples. Look at [https://gobyexample.com/epoch](https://gobyexample.com/epoch)

Comment: should be: return time.Now().UnixNano() / 1000 / 1000

Comment: why not just use  time.Now().Unix instead of the converting?

Comment: Unix() returns seconds.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Use `time.Now().UnixNano() / int64(1e6)` instead.

Comment: @clay this answer will work for all go 1.x.x versions and there for is not wrong,

Answer (score 70):

Keep it simple.

```
func NowAsUnixMilli() int64 {
    return time.Now().UnixNano() / 1e6
}
```

Comment: UnixNano result is undefined if the Unix time in nanoseconds cannot be represented by an int64 (a date before the year 1678 or after 2262)

Answer (score 68):

As @Jono points out in @OneOfOne's answer, the correct answer should take into account the duration of a nanosecond. Eg:

```
func makeTimestamp() int64 {
    return time.Now().UnixNano() / (int64(time.Millisecond)/int64(time.Nanosecond))
}
```

OneOfOne's answer works because `time.Nanosecond` happens to be `1`, and dividing by 1 has no effect. I don't know enough about go to know how likely this is to change in the future, but for the strictly correct answer I would use this function, not OneOfOne's answer. I doubt there is any performance disadvantage as the compiler should be able to optimize this perfectly well.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis

Another way of looking at this is that both `time.Now().UnixNano()` and `time.Millisecond` use the same units (Nanoseconds). As long as that is true, OneOfOne's answer should work perfectly well.

Comment: The value of `.UnixNano()` will *always* be the time in Nanoseconds, `time.Millisecond` will *always* be the value for well, you guessed it, a millisecond, so even if for whatever idiotic reason the constant changes value, dividing UnixNano by Millisecond will *always* return the value in millisecond.

Comment: The units of Unix.Nano is not in question; nor is the value of time.Millisecond. What *is* in question is the unit of time.Millisecond. It happens to be defined in nanoseconds, which is why your answer works. If time.Milliseconds were measured in other units (say, microseconds), the answer you gave would not work.

Comment: @BjornRoche I'm a little late to this party, but wouldn't the correct answer be `(int64(time.Now().UnixNano() / int64(time.Nanosecond))/int64(time.Millisecond)`? The dimensional analysis `ns/(ms/ns)` returns `ns^2/ms`. Your answer also works because `time.Nanosecond=1`, but the units are off...

Comment: @thepuma It's been a while so I might be looking at this wrong or misunderstanding you, but ns/(ms/ns) is equivalent to ns^2/ms, so both answers should work.

Comment: This answer is correct because running this will display the same result as when converting using the online converter https://www.unitconverters.net/prefixes/nano-to-milli.htm

Comment: If you need best performance, turn the denominator into a constant.  There's no reason to recalculate each time you want the current time: var millisConversion = (int64(time.Millisecond)/int64(time.Nanosecond))

Answer (score 13):

> How can I get Unix time in Go in milliseconds?

#### Go 1.17 and above

No more divisions from nanoseconds. Starting from Go 1.17 you can just use [`Time.UnixMilli`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#UnixMilli) method directly:

```
// a deterministic date value
t := time.Date(2021, 7, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

m := t.UnixMilli()
fmt.Println(m) // 1626393600000
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/JSExv5jw2ZW

Answer (score 5):

At https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44196 randall77 suggested

```
time.Now().Sub(time.Unix(0,0)).Milliseconds()
```

which exploits the fact that Go's `time.Duration` already have  `Milliseconds` method.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to round the time to milliseconds before the division.

```
func makeTimestamp() int64 {
    return time.Now().Round(time.Millisecond).UnixNano() / (int64(time.Millisecond)/int64(time.Nanosecond))
}
```

Here is an example program:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println(unixMilli(time.Unix(0, 123400000)))
        fmt.Println(unixMilli(time.Unix(0, 123500000)))
        m := makeTimestampMilli()
        fmt.Println(m)
        fmt.Println(time.Unix(m/1e3, (m%1e3)*int64(time.Millisecond)/int64(time.Nanosecond)))
}

func unixMilli(t time.Time) int64 {
        return t.Round(time.Millisecond).UnixNano() / (int64(time.Millisecond) / int64(time.Nanosecond))
}

func makeTimestampMilli() int64 {
        return unixMilli(time.Now())
}
```

The above program printed the result below on my machine:

```
123
124
1472313624305
2016-08-28 01:00:24.305 +0900 JST
```

Comment: You forgot to mention why you think it's better to round the time to milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Simple-read but precise solution would be:

```
func nowAsUnixMilliseconds(){
    return time.Now().Round(time.Millisecond).UnixNano() / 1e6
}
```

This function:

1. Correctly rounds the value to the nearest millisecond (compare with integer division: it just discards decimal part of the resulting value);
2. Does not dive into Go-specifics of time.Duration coercion — since it uses a numerical constant that represents absolute millisecond/nanosecond divider.

P.S. I've run benchmarks with constant and composite dividers, they showed almost no difference, so feel free to use more readable or more language-strict solution.

Comment: If you want to know the correct Unix time in milliseconds (milliseconds since the Epoch), you should not use Round(), as that will round up half the time, and your result will then contain a millisecond which has not fully elapsed yet.

Comment: Thanks for a note, @torbenl - this may be important for most of systems (mine is an exclusion, this time is stored for history only).