# streaming os/exec.Command

Tags: shell, go, stream, stdout

I want to build a benchmarking tool similar to the unix tool `time`. What I currently have is this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    command := os.Args[1]
    args := os.Args[2:]
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
    start_time := time.Now().UnixNano()
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    print(string(stdout))
    total_time := int64(time.Nanosecond) * (time.Now().UnixNano() - start_time) / int64(time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(total_time)
}
```

My problem with this is, that the output is not streaming, instead it is printed all at once, and weirdly enough for some programs not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to avoid touching the stream altogether. You can pass your own file descriptors for stdout and stderr directly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    command := os.Args[1]
    args := os.Args[2:]
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    start_time := time.Now()

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    total_time := int64(time.Since(start_time) / time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(total_time)
}
```

---

Also, print() should never be used. Instead, use one of the fmt.Print* functions.

---

```
total_time := int64(time.Nanosecond) * (time.Now().UnixNano() - start_time) / int64(time.Millisecond)
```

This line is extremely confusing. `int64(time.Nanosecond) * x` resolves to `1 * x` or just `x`.

Comment: OP probably saw that time * x doesn't work when x is of type int. There's no reason for
`total_time := int64(...`,

Comment: I am saying that multiplying it by Nanosecond is a no-op because Nanosecond = 1.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I'm very new to go and mostly copy and pasting things together from different sources.

Comment: The Nanosecond thing originated from comments in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122821/go-golang-time-now-unixnano-convert-to-milliseconds

Comment: Actually, nvm. My previous suggestion was wrong for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're attempting to do here with `print(string(stdout))` but it's unnecessary and the problems you're facing are likely a side effect of some misuse there.

```
func main() {
    command := os.Args[1]
    args := os.Args[2:]
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    start_time := time.Now().UnixNano()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    total_time := int64(time.Nanosecond) * (time.Now().UnixNano() - start_time) / int64(time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(total_time)
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to see the output of command to be piped to stdout and stderr.

Comment: @DanverBraganza that's a simple change, I'll edit it.