# How to get current time in milliseconds using Go language?

Tags: go, time

I am trying to get the current time in millisecond using Go language https://golang.org/#

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"
func main() {

    now := time.Now()
    secs := now.Unix()
    nanos := now.UnixNano()
    fmt.Println(now)

    millis := nanos / 1000000
    fmt.Println(millis)

}
```

When I run the above code using the mentioned website the output I get is following:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
1257894000000
```

I am not able to understand why I am not getting current date as result? I tried the same code on another website https://www.epochconverter.com/ and got the correct result which is following :

```
Time Now is : 
1496230018
```

Can someone confirm if the problem is related to my code or is the website that's showing the wrong result?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122821/go-golang-time-now-unixnano-convert-to-milliseconds .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you're running this on the Go playground (play.golang.org). The time is fixed on the Go playground, try running it locally instead.