# How to implement Random sleep in golang

Tags: go, random, time, sleep

I am trying to implement random time sleep (in Golang)

```
r := rand.Intn(10)
time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)  //working 
time.Sleep(r * time.Microsecond)    // Not working (mismatched types int and time.Duration)
```

Comment: Related: [conversion of time.Duration type microseconds value to milliseconds in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503758/conversion-of-time-duration-type-microseconds-value-to-milliseconds-in-golang/41503910#41503910).

Comment: [How to multiply duration by integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17573190/86967)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Match the types of argument to `time.Sleep`:

```
r := rand.Intn(10)
time.Sleep(time.Duration(r) * time.Microsecond)
```

This works because `time.Duration` has `int64` as its underlying type:

```
type Duration int64
```

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration

Comment: int64 or uint64 ?

Comment: `time.Sleep((rand.Int63n(10)) * time.Second)`
I tried to pass in int64, but even that doesn't work. @DmytroBogatov is probably correct.

Comment: @PrateekBhuwania try `time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int63n(10))*time.Second)`. There is no automatic type casting in Go. As for my answer it is still correct: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration

Comment: @abhink Yes, your solution is correct. I was just wondering if `time.Second` is an `int64` and `rand.Int63n()` also returns an `int64`, then why is there a type mismatch during multiplication ?

Answer (score 8):

If you try to run same rand.Intn several times, you will see always the same number in output

Just like its written in the official docu https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/

> Top-level functions, such as Float64 and Int, use a default shared Source that produces a deterministic sequence of values each time a program is run. Use the Seed function to initialize the default Source if different behavior is required for each run.

It rather should look like

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
r := rand.Intn(100)
time.Sleep(time.Duration(r) * time.Millisecond)
```